# Pass a table as parameter in openquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, openquery

I've created a datatype and declared a table of this type which I intend to pass as a parameter to an OPENQUERY statement.  `OPENQUERY` returns an error that the object has no columns.
Firstly, the table parameter is defined as follows:

```sql
CREATE TYPE LooseTimecardsTableType AS TABLE ([LABORKEY] [float] NULL)          
GO

DECLARE @DataTable AS LooseTimecardsTableType
INSERT INTO @DataTable
SELECT DISTINCT WOBase.LABORKEY
FROM Lab_WO_DataWH AS WOBase 
left outer JOIN Lab_hrs_DataWH LabHrsWH ON LabHrsWH.WORKORDERLABORKEY = WOBase.LABORKEY
WHERE LabHrsWH.WORKORDERLABORKEY IS NULL AND WOBase.LABORKEY IS NOT NULL AND WOBase.LABORPRICE <> 0
```

The data table returns a single column of `LABORKEY`'s which I want use to restrict the number of records from the `OPENQUERY`.  This in turn is defined as follows:

```sql
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500), @TableVariable LooseTimecardsTableType
SET @SQLString =  N'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(Remoteserver, ''SELECT DISTINCT
    DA.USERNAME, DA.WORKORDERLABORKEY, LB.PERFORMEDBY 
    FROM
    REMOTE.WORKORDERDETAILAUDITS DA
    JOIN REMOTE.WORKORDERLABORBASE LB ON LB.LABORKEY = DA.WORKORDERLABORKEY
    JOIN @TableVariable ON @TableVariable.LABORKEY = LB.LABORKEY
    WHERE DA.WORKORDERAUDITCATEGORY = 0'')'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, N'@TableVariable LooseTimecardsTableType READONLY', @DataTable
```

Please assist in getting this to work

Comment: You can't pass parameters to `OPENQUERY`. `@TableVariable` is being referenced within `OPENQUERY`'s second parameter, and thus it has no context there.

Comment: At first glance it seems you can join the table variable to your OPENQUERY results instead of using dynamic SQL, but it depends on the data.  Please always provide sample data and expected results (text format, not a screenshot) with questions about queries.

Comment: You are right, the table variable can be joined to the OPENQUERY results.   Under these circumstances The OPENQUERY runs extremely slowly.  The point of the parameters is actually to speed up the OPENQUERY and I would love it to work inside OPENQUERY

Comment: Aside from `OPENQUERY` not supporting parameters, table-valued parameters can't be remoted through another mechanism either (linked server, `EXECUTE .. AT`). As this is just a collection of scalars, you could interpolate the values into the string (i.e. generate an `IN` clause), or generate an `INSERT ... FROM (VALUES ...)` statement to produce a temp table on the remote side (or indeed a TVP) that you then join on. Alternatively, if the remote data is not too large, pull that over first and then process it (i.e. make the mountain come to you).

Comment: I must admit, joining on a `float` seems like a very poor choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table variable cannot be passed as a parameter to OPENQUERY.  As my table had only a single column I was able to convert it to a string and pass the string to OPENQUERY as a parameter.  I did this within a procedure that accepts a table variable.  After  parsing the table to a string, the procedure also runs the OPENQUERY.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  PRM_LIST ( @TableVariable LooseTimecardsTableType  READONLY)
AS
DECLARE
@LBKY_NVAR NVARCHAR(2500),
@POINTER INT,
@SQLString NVARCHAR(max)

SELECT @POINTER =  MIN(LABORKEY) FROM @TableVariable
WHILE @POINTER IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
SET @LBKY_NVAR = IIF(@LBKY_NVAR IS NULL,'('+''''+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,@POINTER) + '''',
@LBKY_NVAR + ',' + ''''+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,@POINTER) + '''')
SELECT @POINTER =  MIN(LABORKEY) FROM @TableVariable WHERE LABORKEY > @POINTER
END
SET @LBKY_NVAR = @LBKY_NVAR +  ')'
SET @LBKY_NVAR = REPLACE(@LBKY_NVAR,'''','''''')

SET @SQLString =
N'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(REMOTE, ''SELECT DISTINCT
DA.USERNAME, DA.WORKORDERLABORKEY, LB.PERFORMEDBY 
FROM
REMOTE.WORKORDERDETAILAUDITS DA
JOIN REMOTE.WORKORDERLABORBASE LB ON LB.LABORKEY = DA.WORKORDERLABORKEY
WHERE DA.WORKORDERAUDITCATEGORY = 0
AND LB.LABORKEY IN '+CAST(@LBKY_NVAR AS nvarchar(2500))+ N'
'')'
EXEC (@SQLString)
GO
```

The procedure call is:

```
EXECUTE PRM_LIST @DATATABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a table variable you could turn the select statement that populates the table into a view using the where clause and then join the view to the table on the remote server.